# X11 keyboard utility to display key presses?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, xorg

I'm having trouble with an Asus Q500A laptop and its hotkeys under Fedora 20. They are the function keys that turn the wifi radio on/off, change keyboard backlight, the display brightness, volume up/down/mute, etc. They are paired with the function keys on this laptop, and the hotkeys simply don't work.

What utility is available to run to see if the hotkeys are recognized? That is, I want to run `<some program>` and toggle the wifi radio state to see if it registers; increase the volume and see if it registers; increase the screen brightness and see if it registers; etc.

This is part of a bigger problem with dual monitor configuration and the primary monitor being almost completely black (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1047684). I'm trying to increase the brightness so I can see the log-in screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xev` will show you X event keypresses, as well as low-level information about the keypress.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Magically, the Function keys and the Hotkeys started working once I ran `xev`. The Sleep key (F1) worked, the Bright Up (F6) and the Bright Down (F7) worked. The Radio On/Off (F2) did not work, and the keyboard backlight died. All in all, I think its a step forward. I'd love to give you a +10 for that answer.